# Want Checked Item From Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I am working with listview in C# webapplication. My Problem is I want checked Items from the listview . I have try with find selecteditem and all. I dont know how to get checked items from checkbox inside listview.My code is as follows:-

**aspx**

```
    <asp:ListView ID="PackagesListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="PackagesDataSource" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" 
      GroupItemCount="4" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder" OnItemDataBound="PackagesListView_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <table style="margin-left:0px; width:570; table-layout:fixed; overflow:hidden;">
        <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server" >
        </tr>
      </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
      <tr class="productsTableRow">
        <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
      </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
      <td style="width:140px;">
        <div style="text-align:center; line-height:1.5;"><asp:Label ID="PackageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' /></div>
        <div style="text-align:center;"><asp:CheckBox ID="PackageCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="OnPackageSelected" AutoPostBack="true" PackageID='<%#Eval("PackageID")%>' /></div>
      </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
   <asp:Button ID="ButtonSaveQuotation" runat="server" Text="Save Quotation" 
                  CssClass="button" Visible="false" onclick="ButtonSaveQuotation_Click1" />
```

**aspx.cs**

```
     protected void ButtonSaveQuotation_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    }
```

so here in sb I want to append text of all the label whose checkboxes are checked.Thank You

Comment: Can you use ListView.CheckedItems ?

Comment: Do you mean for my example PackagesListView.CheckedItems right? No I dont know why but I dont have that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find the checkbox since it's inside the template field
Example:

```
if (PackagesListView.Items.Count > 0)
{                
    for (int i = 0; i < PackagesListView.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox PackageCheckBox= (CheckBox)PackagesListView.Items[i].FindControl("PackageCheckBox");
        if (PackageCheckBox!= null)
        {
            if (PackageCheckBox.Checked.Equals(true))
            {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in PackagesListView.Items.Where(i => ((CheckBox)i.FindControl("PackageCheckBox")).Checked))
{
    var label =(Label) item.FindControl("PackageLabel");
    label.Text += " Appended text";
}
```

Perhaps this will help you? This should go after page load. Also make sure you are not rebinding your listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
var texts = PackagesListView.Items.Cast<Control>()
                .Where(c => ((CheckBox)c.FindControl("PackageCheckBox")).Checked)
                .Select(c => ((Label)c.FindControl("PackageLabel")).Text);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach ( var text in texts)
   sb.AppendLine(text);
```